# Multi-domain Azure connect to single local domain controller

Tags: active-directory, azure, windows-server-2016, entra-id

I am wanting to complete the following.

Azure AD:

Domain1
Domain2

Azure AD Connect

Single local domain controller

I apologize for my formatting beforehand. But is it possible to sync users/attributes from both domain 1 and domain 2 onto a local domain controller to facilitate single sign on for two domains, and one local domain controller?

Best regards,

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense. You don't sync from Azure AD to local AD, you sync from local AD to Azure AD. Could you explain what you're trying to do in more detail?

Comment: My apologies. I guess I wasn't fully sure what we needed but here is the solution that ended up working. I wasn't sure if you were able to take two office 365 domains under one tenancy and have it sync with Azure AD connect to a single local domain for both domains. What I did was added in a UPN suffix for both domains in the Windows domain and they were able to sync to the Microsoft domains and enable SSO without any issues. Sorry for the confusion my lack of understanding made my wording terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup used the following:

Microsoft Domain 1
Microsoft Domain 2

Both under a single tenancy for management. 1 Azure AD connect enabled local Windows AD. Synced users from either domains by utilizing add-in UPN suffixes.